# Capturing global paste event using hook to WH_GETMESSAGE not working

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

**Purpose:**
To capture global paste. Whenever any of ctrl + v, edit->paste and right click->paste is done in any application. Be it file paste or text paste.

For that, I am installing a hook to the WH_GETMESSAGE and check for WM_PASTE message using the `message` parameter of `MSG` structure returned. Following is the hook dll source:

```
//Hook DLL source    

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Shared by all processes variables
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.HKT,RWS")
#pragma data_seg(".HKT")
// The hook handle
HHOOK sg_hGetMsgHook       = NULL;
// Indicates whether the hook has been installed
BOOL  sg_bHookInstalled    = FALSE;
// get this from the application who calls SetWindowsHookEx()'s wrapper
HWND  sg_hwndServer        = NULL; 
#pragma data_seg()

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Forward declarations
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 __declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI InstallHook(
    BOOL bActivate, 
    HWND hWndServer
    );

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(
    int code,       // hook code
    WPARAM wParam,  // removal option
    LPARAM lParam   // message
    );

HMODULE hDLL;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Definitions
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch(ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hDLL = hModule;
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(sg_hGetMsgHook);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// InstallHook
// This function is exported
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOL WINAPI InstallHook(
    BOOL bActivate, 
    HWND hWndServer
    )
{
    if(hWndServer)
    {
        sg_hwndServer = hWndServer;
    }

    if(bActivate)
    {
        sg_hGetMsgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, hDLL, NULL);
        if(!sg_hGetMsgHook)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(sg_hGetMsgHook)
        {
            return UnhookWindowsHookEx(sg_hGetMsgHook);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GetMsgProc
//
// Filter function for the WH_GETMESSAGE
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(
    int code,       // hook code
    WPARAM wParam,  // removal option
    LPARAM lParam   // message
    )
{
    if(code == HC_ACTION)   // if there is an incoming action and a key was pressed
    {
        MSG * lpMsg = (MSG *)lParam;
        if(lpMsg->message == WM_PASTE)
        {
            PostMessage(sg_hwndServer, WM_USER + 100, 0,0);
        }
    }

    //
    // We must pass the all messages on to CallNextHookEx.
    //
    return ::CallNextHookEx(sg_hGetMsgHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The custom message `WM_USER + 100` is supposed to be posted to the window whenever a paste event happens (ctrl + v, edit->paste, right click->paste). But it does not happen.

To ensure whether this implementation is correct, I tried hooking to WH_KEYBOARD and posted the same message whenever space is clicked, and the message is received correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Please share your valuable thoughts on this.

Comment: Well, no, WM_PASTE is an sent message, delivered synchronously, so won't be returned by GetMessage. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the goal is to capture whenever paste happens (any of ctrl + v, edit->paste and right click->paste). Be it file paste or text paste. What do u mean by sent message?

Comment: There's no reason a "paste event" in an application has to involve the `WM_PASTE` message, which is only really used for edit controls.

Comment: If that is your goal, you should ask about it. Because the answer to this question won't really help you proceed. That sent, if you don't know the difference between sent and queued messages, you need to back up and gain the necessary grounding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my ultimate purpose in the post. I shall first explore more about the messaging architecture of Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable "*A clipboard viewer is notified, whenever the contents of the clipboard change*" - but not when a paste is performed, or even when the clipboard is accessed for any reason other than modifying the content

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True, I mixed up *"copy"* and *"paste"* in my head. Probably because I couldn't even think of a reason to want to get notified about paste operations.